# Destructuring My MUI Text Field Causes It To Break

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, material-ui, formik-material-ui

**Goal:** Destructure repetitive components and pass in props to one component for more clear code.

**Issue:**  When copying my MUI `TextField` component exactly, and then passing it back into the main return, it breaks the component. Whilst typing was slow with formik validation on `localhost`, it now escapes the `TextField` upon typing, and only permits one character at a time before requiring the user to click back into the `TextField`.

Code:

```
const SimpleTextField = () => {
    return (
      <TextField
        disabled={vacancyStatus === "Expired"}
        label="Insurance 2"
        variant="outlined"
        name={"insurance"}
        datacy={"insurance"}
        fullWidth
        value={formik.values.insurance}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        error={formik.touched.insurance && Boolean(formik.errors.insurance)}
        helperText={formik.touched.insurance && formik.errors.insurance}
      />
    )
  }
```

***Note:*** *All I did was copy the `TextField` component, add it to `SimpleTextField`, and then put `<SimpleTextField />` back into the main return. The `TextField` component works when not destructured.*

**Package.json (shortened)**

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/cache": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
    "@emotion/server": "^11.4.0",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.6.0",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.0-alpha.2",
    "card-validator": "^8.1.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express-jwt": "^7.7.5",
    "formik": "^2.2.6",
    "next": "12.1.5",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-countup": "^6.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.4.5",
    "react-visibility-sensor": "^5.1.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
```